# App got removed from PlayStore due to accessibility permission

Tags: android, google-play, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Google has removed the app due to below **Policy Violation**

Policy: *Apps requesting accessibility services should only be used to help users with disabilities use Android devices and apps.*

*If you aren’t already doing so, you must explain to users how your app is using the ‘android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE’ to help users with disabilities use Android devices and apps. Apps that fail to meet this requirement within 30 days may be removed from Google Play*

There are few applications (**Kaspersky Mobile Antivirus, Avast Mobile Security**) on PlayStore who are using accessibility permission, How they are able to do so without violating Google Policy?

Comment: You need to provide proper privacy policy with all your requirements of using such permissions.. This should solve your problem.. and Google team will understand your need and allow you to access such permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Prior to this rule, there were quite a few apps on the play store that were utilizing the abilities of Accessibility Services for questionable purposes. Unless you talk to Google directly, if your app binds as an Accessibility Service and does not provide benefit to users with disabilities, it will be removed/won't pass the review process.

Accessibility Services can do a lot of nefarious things:

1. Read Screen Content
2. Perform Actions on Users Behalf (click things)
3. Enter Text into edit boxes
4. Forceably go back to the home screen
5. Capture key strokes
6. etc.

So companies that are not well known/trusted and that aren't providing services for users with disabilities are going to have a rough time getting around this. Strictly speaking Kaspersky and Avast do not provide any particular benefit to users with disabilities, however, they are obviously not within the realms of the apps that Google was targeting with the "spirit" of that rule. They have clearly reached out to Google and discussed how they are delivering value through the Accessibility APIs and Google has deemed those apps acceptable.

A quick chat with a Senior App Reviewer to show how you're using Accessibility Service permissions may get you around this, it may not. It is certainly worth reaching out and talking to someone. Since AntiVirus has been allowed through, despite not being adherent to the letter of the law, clearly Google is willing to bend on this one. How far and whether or not you will get the same level of trust... I suppose that is for you to find out.